# C - Modifying function parameter

Tags: c, string, function, parameter-passing

I'm trying to simulate passing by reference and apparently I'm doing something wrong:

```
long int toNumber(char * input) {
   char* pointer;
   long int number;
   number = strtol(input, &pointer, 10);
   if (number == 0L) {
       return -1337;
   } else {
       input = pointer;
       return number;
   }
}
```

I'd like for this function to return the value of the input and trim the converted beginning of it, yet when I try calling it, even though the integer conversion is flawless, the string remains the same. Thanks for any kind of help.

Edit:

```
    char* input = "123 456"; 
    long int number = toNumber(input);
```

Edit 2: Changed back, sorry.
I'd like for it to work something like this:
input = 123 456 -> number = 123, input = 456 -> number = 456, input = NULL

Comment: By changing the code in your question, you've changed the question and invalided any existing answers. Your revised code, when I run it on my system, dies with a segmentation fault because it attempts to modify a string literal.

Comment: When posting examples, it helps to state the expected results. So you expect the function to return 123456... and a string to change somehow?

Comment: I expect it to return 123 and for the input to change to "456".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear about the 1337 thing... however, this code should produce what the question code is attempting with simplified logic.

```
long int toNumber(char **input) 
   { 
   char *pointer;
   long int number;

   number = strtol(input, &pointer, 10);
   if(number)
      *input = pointer;
   else
      number = (1337);

   return number;
   }
```

Something like the following call the above function:

```
   {
   char *test="123 456";
   long int n;

   ...

   n = toNumber(&test);

   printf("n[%ld] remainder[%s]\n", n, test);       
   ...

   }
```

Which should print:

```
n[123] remainder[ 456]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Only I had to edit it to "strtol(*input,...". The "-1337" is an arbitrarily picked number used to indicate invalid parsing.

Answer (score 1):

`input` is a pointer, which is passed *by value* to your `toNumber` function. Assigning a value to `input` merely changes the parameter object, which is local to the function. It has no effect on the caller.

To modify the string, you'd have to modify `*input`, or `input[some_index]`, or pass `input` to some other function that will modify the data that it points to.

Note that updating a string in place is not necessarily a good idea. You can modify the characters that make up the string, but you can't increase the size of the array containing the string. And if the caller passes a string literal, then attempting to modify it has undefined behavior (and will likely crash your program).

Comment: I tried *input = *pointer and it doesn't help either. I thought it would be useful for my scenario, I have a long string of a set length of numbers and words and if one of the inputs was wrong, this way I could discard the whole thing without wasting time on exploding it into an array or something like that. Thanks anyway.